# Could be jquery used to modify html strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have for example such piece of html:

```
var html = '<p>Title</p><b>edit me</b><i>remove me</i>';
```

I want to change title in it, but do not want to use regexp or string replace
functions for this, because if title would match tag name, then html could be corrupted.

I now trying to adopt jQuery for this, because it seems capable, but in reality things not so easy. Here is code:

```
$( $(html)[0] ).text('New title');
console.log(html); // --> prints out original html with old title
```

Any idea how to make this code work if it is at all possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html = $('<div/>').html(html).find('p').text('New title').end().html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bEUHN/

Note: There are 3 wrapper elements in the created jQuery object using `$(html)`, for selecting the `p` element you should use `filter` method.

```
$(html).filter('p').text('New title');
```

Comment: Note: the main point here is to assign the value back to the `html` variable.

Comment: This solution looks little hacky, is it possible to make it without wrapper elements ?

Comment: @Dfr Since there is no wrapper element in your string, it's the best and shortest way as far as I know.